# React- Apollo Client- structuring components

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, next.js

Let's say component - TodoList need to show the list of TODO's in 2 different ways, listview and gridview .there is a switch on the page that toggles between the views. Assuming I want to keep the 2 views as different components, what is the best practice -

1. create TodoList component with graphql query and then pass the result of the query to TODOListView and TODOGridView components?
2. create TodoList component with NO graphql query and then write the same grqphql query inTODOListView and TODOGridView components (not DRY, query duplication in each component, but apollo cache will make sure that it is not called multiple times)?

good/bad with each approach?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO **there is no real choice**, cache usage has no value as argument then no good parts with second approach.

**Taking usability, UX, user centric design you probably want to keep page, sorting and filtering state while switching type of view**. As an user you're expecting this kind of behaviour. This is easily available only with first solution.

> Assuming I want to keep the 2 views as different components

IMHO this is wrong assumption, too. Of course you can do that but Lists are almost the same, the real difference is in item/row rendering. **If this is a simple styling sets change** (or adding a few elements) then **even no need for using components for items**, just conditional rendering. You can change/refactor it later.

Utilizing item components you can have additional abstraction layer and more complex use cases available. With passed down (into items) switching type handler I was able to change it (gloablly) from simgle item level or change locally item view type - mixed element list.

Comment: Totally agree to your suggestions. my question was also related to how it is being done when graphql comes into picture. what is the best practice of writing gql within these components ..

Comment: I rote about this (cache) in the first sentence ;)

Comment: it will work the same with graphql, redux or other centralised (cached or not) data sources. DRY and far easier management in the future wins.